# What is the optimum way to design this simple table with 3 unique columns in this case?

Tags: sql, database-design, query-optimization

Say, I got a table with 3 columns (varchar type), the Unique key= the combination of the 3 columns.
Should I create 1 more column (int type) & set the primary key for it, of course we still set the unique (column1, column2, column3)?

So which one is better? 3 unique columns or 4 columns (1 primary key + 3 unique columns)
and why you think that option is better?

Answer (score 1):

One advantage to the extra pseudo key column is that it's easier to create FKs to your table since you only have one column to reference

Answer (score 1):

There are three sane ways to build that table.  The underlying relational principle is that all known constraints *must* be declared to the dbms, so the dbms can enforce them. In all cases, the three columns that contain real data probably have to be declared NOT NULL.

```
create table wibble (
  column_1 data-type not null,
  column_2 data-type not null,
  column_3 data-type not null,
  primary key (column_1, column_2, column_3)
);

create table wibble (
  surrogate_id_number integer primary key,
  column_1 data-type not null,
  column_2 data-type not null,
  column_3 data-type not null,
  unique (column_1, column_2, column_3)
);

create table wibble (
  surrogate_id_number integer not null unique,
  column_1 data-type not null,
  column_2 data-type not null,
  column_3 data-type not null,
  primary key (column_1, column_2, column_3)
);
```

It should be obvious that a primary key constraint alone on an ID number column can't possibly work. *That* would allow duplicated data like this.

```
1  Value1  Value2  Value3
2  Value1  Value2  Value3
3  Value1  Value2  Value3
4  Value1  Value2  Value3
5  Value1  Value2  Value3
```

Answer (score 0):

As per me you should make all column as primary key,as it never allows null value and primary key index is the most effective access path for the tabl.
Instead of this it depends on your requirement whether int type id is required or not.